# IIS - Rewrite Url virtual url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have two web apps written in net framework 4.5. the first is a frontend app and the second is a backend app that exposes some api. The two are on two independent domains and also on different ports. The first app makes calls to the second's api with jquery.
this way the browser must be able to reach both domains and both ports. Instead, I would like the browser to only reach the frontend and IIS forwards with url rewriter to the backend. To do this I would like jquery to make calls to the same domain as the frontend on a path that is not real, but virtual, for example /api, virtual because on the frontend there is no api folder with resources and all requests to /api were forwarded to the backend. I wrote the following rule, but I get http error 502

```
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite API requests" enabled="true">
          <match url="^api/(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api/" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api.dominio.local/api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

Comment: You can study what's behind the scenes with FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Likely the condition you set isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a reverse proxy on IIS, you need to install the application request routing module.

After installing the required software, follow the steps below.

- Open IIS Manager.
- Select your server in the Connections pane on the left.
- In the center pane, double-click the application request routing cache.
- Click "Server Proxy Settings" on the right.
- Check the "Enable proxy" box and click "Apply".

[image]

After enabling the proxy, clear the browser cache and try the rewrite rule again to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, my solution worked, I restarted IIS and it worked.

Comment: Did you make no other changes and just restart IIS?